# SQL While que recorre una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, while

Amigos estoy tratando de recorrer una tabla desde SQL pero por alguna razón no obtengo los datos de cada fila de mi tabla. Alguién me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?

```js
declare @count int = 0,
  @countb int = 1
set @count = (select count( * ) from stats_ddl)
while @countb <= @count
begin
declare @fechaMov varchar(50) = (select top(1) fecha + hora + importe from stats_ddl)
print 'fecha' + @fechaMov + ' ' + convert(varchar, @countb)
set @countb = @countb + 1
end
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes crear una tabla temporal, ir eliminando el primer elemento en cada iteración e ir seteando el count nuevamente, para que puedas trabajar con el while

Comment: te recomiendo hacer uso de un cursor para realizar esa tarea. Creo que es lo as apropiado. Aprender a manejar los mismos te va a ser de mucha utilidad para tareas futuras. Mas abajo te dejo un link con un tutorial y ejemplos. Espero que te sirva la información. Saludos! https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19267.manejo-de-cursores-en-sql-server-es-es.aspx

Comment: Tu while esta bien, ahora tienes que ver lo que esta haciendo por cada registro va y te trae el primer registro de la tabla stats_ddl y en cada iteración siempre pides que te traiga top(1), si lo que quisieras es que cambiara de acuerdo al ID de stats_ddl tendrias que hacer algo así: select  fecha + hora + importe from stats_ddl where ID_stats_ddl = @countb y así en cada iteración te trairia la fila correspondiente.

Comment: `top(1)` siempre te va a traer el primer registro. Explica un poco más que es lo que buscas así como la definición de la tabla, para que podamos ayudarte, hay varias soluciones posibles que ya te han comentado, pero para desarollarlas necesitamos más información. Saludos

Comment: Tu objetivo al hacer esto es agregarle un numero de fila a cada registro?

Comment: no solo necesito que me devuelva todos los datos por fila para que pueda operar con ellos dentro del mismo query, necesito tomar ciertos datos y ponerlos en otra tabla

Comment: En ese caso necesitas usar los CURSORES como te comenta Fran, aquí igual hay una pregunta donde expone el uso de los mismos. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513986/how-to-write-a-foreach-in-sql-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amigo intenta hacer esto, debes clonar tu tabla en una tabla temporal e iterar:

```
DECLARE @count INT;

CREATE TABLE #stats_ddl(
    fecha DATETIME, 
    hora TIME,
    importe DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO #stats_ddl 
SELECT * FROM stats_ddl

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #stats_ddl;

WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fechaMov VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT TOP(1) fecha + hora + importe FROM #stats_ddl);
    PRINT 'fecha' + @fechaMov + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @count);
    DELETE TOP (1) FROM #stats_ddl
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #stats_ddl;
END

DROP TABLE #stats_ddl;
```